# facebook likebox popup breaking layout

Tags: jquery, html

Hi guys my friend asked me to help him with his site. His request was to do the facebook likebox popup for his website, I've copied the HTML, CSS and made it locally and it works.

Then He pasted it where it should be in his page and instead of working properly it is displaying on the top of the site, breaking whole layout. I really don't have idea why it behave that way.

Anyone will lend a helpful hand or thought?

http://psiaki.apnet.pl/ this is this site, he restore it so no popup but it was in the right top corner.

below there is my code on codepen.io

http://codepen.io/niziou/pen/ptsmk

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" /><script>$(function() { $( "#dialog" ).dialog(); }); </script>
```

It's clearly working fine right?

Comment: It is working fine on CodePen. My guess is that either 1) the CSS is missing when it's on your friend's site, or 2) some CSS from that site is overriding yours. Hard to say without seeing it.

Comment: Please paste all the relevant parts of your code here, instead of linking to an external resources. Live pages, like the one you've linked, are extremely susceptible to rapid change, diminishing the future knowledge value of this question for future visitors and making it more difficult for potential answerers to inspect your code.

Comment: @isherood the thing is there is no css rules for my popup, so it has to be 2. some CSS overriding rules
also esqew I get it mate, but I don't know if I suppose to paste the whole css file here?